# cufontext tag styling not working

Tags: html, css

```
<cufontext style="color:red">Home</cufontext>
```

I want the text color of 'Home' to be red

I tried `<cufontext style="color:red !important">Home</cufontext>` as well

No luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using classes as cufon selectors instead?
Html:

```
<p class='cufon red'>Hello world</p>
```

Css:

```
.red
{
    color:red;
}
```

And JS:

```
Cufon.replace('.cufon');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sE39M/

Comment: Im trying to change the menu color of a theme. Cufon.replace('.cufon'); is already done by the theme so that still no luck. Is there any way to override ?